# SSIS Packages are not listed in integration services

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

We have multiple SSIS packages deployed on a production box. All the scheduled jobs that call these packages run fine.

Whenever I create a new package and try to deploy, I can see the folder structure and deploy fine.

Here is the problem I am facing:

When I log into integration services from SSMS, none of the deployed packages are visible. The tree structure under "Stored Packages" does not expand.

The setup is a 64 bit cluster running SQL 2005 9.0.4226

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Raj

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of troubleshooting questions:

1. Is this problem specific to your machine?
2. Can you duplicate the problem from another machine?
3. If you log into the server itself and use its version of SSMS, does it also have the problem?
4. Have you tried reinstalling SQL Server 2008 on the server?
5. Are you able to the see File System and MSDB folders under Stored Packages or does it just never expand Stored Packages at all as you implied in your post?
6. If you run the following queries, do they return any values?  The first query should display the list of folders including a Maintenance Plans folder and a blank folder.  The second query should show all of your deployed packages if you are relying on server storage.

select *

from msdb.dbo.sysssispackagefolders

select *

from msdb.dbo.sysssispackages

Comment: Thanks. Answers: 1. Yes; 2. No 3. Yes; 4. Server uses SQL 2005. Cannot reinstall as it is a production box and a cluster. 5. No. When you click on the + to expand, the + vanishes. 6. Yes. The SQL returns folders and packages correctly.

Comment: If you are saying the problem DOESN'T exist on the server but it does in your local SSMS client then it is likely the problem is with your machine.  Have you tried reinstalling your SSMS on your computer?  At different times various team members of mine (myself included) have had individual problems with either SSMS or BIDS.  We usually resolve these issues by reinstalling or reregistering a specific component of the affected application.  If the problem doesn't exist on the server, then it is likely a problem with one component of your computer that can be fixed with a repair/install.